Keyboard stopped working suddenly on YogaC940
today out of nowhere (my laptop was in sleep mode) when I tried continuing work after lunch break my keyboard suddenly stopped working. I tried multiple troubleshooting steps (including reinstalling Ubuntu) but no chance.
I have dual boot, and on Windows, in the grub menu etc. everything’s perfectly fine. Tablet mode switch works in windows as well (deactivating keyboard when the laptop is flipped into tablet mode).
I now found out on Xorg, the keyboard is working after i logged in (via the touchscreen keyboard). On regular Wayland not though. The only issues i had before was sometimes tablet mode being falsely recognized / not back to laptop mode after using it as a tablet. Reboots usually solved the issue.
Anybody have explanations or fixes for this ?
Thanks.
